# List of bad tags

Tags: discussion, tags

This question contains a list of tags that are not useful and should be removed from any question should they appear again. This applies mostly to so-called meta tags, see also [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for more information.

If you see a new tag like this please remove it from the relevant question and add it to this list. We'll also try to keep a counter how often the tags reappear to keep track of the most problematic ones. Please only add tags that you really encountered, don't preemptively add bad tags that haven't appeared yet.

Answer (score 4):

- [debunk](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debunk) 3x
- [evidence](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence) 7x
- [myths](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myths) 2x
- [pseudoscience](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudoscience) 2x
- [quackery](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quackery) 1x
- [rationality](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rationality) 1x
- [research](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) 2x (created [scientific-research](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-research) for one question where it was used differently)
- [scam](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scam) 12x
- [science](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) 6x
- [urban-legend](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urban-legend) 2x
- [urban-myths](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urban-myths) 1x

Comment: Your position on research/scientific-research is a little unclear.

Comment: @Odd the original exception was for questions that are about claims related to scientific research itself. E.g. there was a widely publicized claim that x percent of published research is false, that would be something that should be tagged "scientific-research". The tag is misapplied a lot, so I would not argue against removing it to prevent this from happening. But there are legimitate applications for that tag.

Comment: Please add a rationale on why the individual tags are bad. I don’t always see it. In particular for “myths” and “scam”.

Comment: @Konrad, "myths" and "scams" are presupposing the answer to the question. Typically, if the answer is the claim is true, it is neither a myth nor a scam. The skeptical approach is not to conclude it is a myth until it has been investigated in some way. (Concluding it is a scam requires even more evidence that there is a deliberate effort.)