# Can we burninate the science tag already?

Tags: discussion, tag-blacklisting

I just removed another science tag on a question. I think pretty much every question on this site could be tagged science. It's an absurdly useless meta tag, and I'm getting tired of seeing it.

Can we burninate it already?

PS: This also applies to some of [these other bad tags](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/list-of-bad-tags/50#50).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

(there were only 5 of these...)

Comment: I keep removing them when I see them. That's why there were only 5.

Comment: all right, if it naturally recurs just comment here again and I'll blacklist it