# Cleaning up [money] /[finance]/[currency] tags

Tags: discussion

@Sklivvz asked us to [look at some problematic tags](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/our-tags-need-your-attention).

I don't think the [money](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) or [finance](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) are doing anyone any good. Finance is too broad, and money is too vague. What should we do?

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia explains that [finance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finance).

> can be broken into three different sub-categories: public finance, corporate finance and personal finance.

I think this is what we need to move to: three tags to cover money and finance:

- [public-finance](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-finance) for discussing governments' policies and practices.
- [corporate-finance](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corporate-finance) for example, discussing how much money some company is worth or how women are paid compared to men.
- [personal-finance](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-finance) for example, whether day-traders lose money.

Questions specifically about coins and notes belong under [currency](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency).

Comment: My only conundrum is: can we expect the community to use these properly? Is there a simpler possibility?